# Strict nVidia OpenGL support (OpenGL 3.2)

Tags: opengl, nvidia

While AMD is following the OpenGL specification very strict, nVidia often works even when the specification is not followed. One example is that nVidia supports element incides (used in `glDrawElements`) on the CPU memory, whereas AMD only supports element indices from a element array buffer.

My question is: Is there a way to enforce strict OpenGL behaviour using a nVidia driver? Currently I'm interested in a solution for a Windows/OpenGL 3.2/FreeGlut/GLEW setup.

Edit: If it is not possible to enforce strict behaviour on the driver itself - is there some OpenGL proxy that guarantees strict behaviour (such as GLIntercept)

Comment: I've had code run "perfectly" on an nVidia card and then crash spectacularly on AMD cards. Unfortunately all I could do was make extensive use of glGetError() as even though you get the error, nVidia sometimes just works anyway. I would also look into the ARB_Debug_output if you can, I'm sure that's >= 4.x though.

Comment: Using a core profile context is supposed to be a _very strong_ hint to the driver to disallow deprecated behavior. But I have seen all of the vendors allow things in a core context that are only supposed to work in compatibility profiles. If you really want to enforce strict conformance the best way to do this is to familiarize yourself with the specification and only use features that are _supposed_ to be available in your context :P That said, gDEBugger can be configured to warn you whenever you make a deprecated API call.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman My problem is not a deprecated API call - but rather a deprecated usage, so I don't think that gDEBugger or GLIntercept will find such issues (?).

Comment: It should, it tests for deprecated tokens in the API calls too. Such as `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` in a call to `glTexImage2D (...)`. However, determining whether a passed pointer is to client memory or an offset into a VBO is much more difficult, and I suppose the only way to detect this behavior would be for it to test if an element array VBO was bound. I have never tried this situation myself, so I do not know if it is capable of detecting this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No vendor enforces the specification strictly. Be it AMD, nVidia, Intel, PowerVR, ... they all have their idiosyncrasies and you have to learn to live with them, sadly. That is one of the annoying things about having each vendor implement their own GLSL compiler, as opposed to Microsoft implementing the one and only HLSL compiler in D3D.

The [ANGLE project](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) tries to mitigate this to a certain extent by providing a single shader validator shared across many of the major web browsers, but it is an uphill battle and this only applies to WebGL for the most part. You will always have implementation differences when every vendor implements the entire API themselves.

Now that Khronos group has seriously taken on the task of establishing a set of conformance tests for desktop OpenGL like they have for WebGL / OpenGL ES, things might start to get a little bit better. But forcing a driver to operate in a strict conformance mode is not really a standard thing - there may be `#pragmas` and such that hint the compiler to behave more strictly, but these are all vendor specific.

By the way, I realize this question has nothing to do with GLSL *per-se*, but it was the best example I could give.

Comment: I Just want to chime in on that standard GLSL compiler thing. Something that I always missed about modern OpenGL was the lack to supply shaders in a more low-level fashion, something like an AST or some kind of intermediary low level code (like for example the LLVM intermediary, that then gets translated into optimized machine code by the architecture backend). That would have allowed for people inventing their own shader language frontends, made development of runtime shader generators easier and most importantly would have allowed development and publication of a standard GLSL compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way you can be sure that your OpenGL code will work on your target hardware is to test it. In theory simply writing standard compliant code should work everywhere, but sadly this isn't always the case.